# Leaflet markercluster rails not displaying marker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, leaflet.markercluster

I am not get a graphic for my markercluster, just a number.  I suspect the css is missing, but am not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I get no errors in the console, and everythings works ok without markercluster.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'
gem 'leaflet-rails'
gem 'leaflet-markercluster-rails'
gem 'gon'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require leaflet
//= require leaflet-google
//= require leaflet.markercluster
//= require_tree
```

**application.css**

```
 *= require leaflet
 *= require leaflet.markercluster
 *= require leaflet.markercluster.default
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

**coffeescript**

```
$ ->
    map = L.map("mapid").setView([47.6345153, -122.3208297], 18)
    map.options.maxZoom = 22
    map.options.bounceAtZoomLimits = true
    googleLayer = new L.Google("ROADMAP")
    map.addLayer googleLayer
    markers = L.markerClusterGroup()

    for i in[0...10]
        markers.addLayer L.marker([47.6345 + (Math.random() / 2000), -122.3208 + (Math.random() / 2000)])
    markers.refreshClusters
    map.addLayer markers
```

Any help would be wonderful.

[image: Sample of google map with leaflet markerclusters not working]

Comment: `L.markerClusterGroup([47.6345153, -122.3208297])` is weird: it is supposed to receive an array of markers (or nothing), not coordinates.

Comment: Good catch @ghybs - sadly it doesn't make any difference.  It must have been some artifact from when I was messing around.

I've updated my post, and changed the code type from javascript to coffeescript just to make things clear for everybody.

I've also added an image showing the marker clusters (numbers only) and the area where the markers are.

Comment: *bump*  Wondering if anybody has any help or suggestions.  I'm sure I'm missing something, but can't figure out what it is.

I've tried using normal markers, icon markers, json markers, divIcon markers and they all show up when they are single, but only show a number when they are clusters.

I've also transfered the code to another machine. No luck.  Tried other basemaps.  No luck.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out leaflet-markercluster-rails was using code from leaflet-markercluster 0.4, not the more current 0.7.  From what I can tell, that's the root of my entire problem. :)

Comment: I am having the same issue.  How did you end up solving the problem?

Comment: Seemed to have been a problem with versions.  Using a different gem seemed to fix the issue.

 gem 'rails-assets-leaflet',  source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
 gem 'rails-assets-leaflet.markercluster', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'